# Make all variables readonly and local by default in bash

Tags: bash, variable, macos

When building `bash` scripts, I use a lot of `readonly` and `local -r` when making variables. That rapidly fills a script and makes the code less readable (and repetitive). Is there a way (like a `set` flag at the top of the script) to make all variables `readonly` and/or `local -r` by default?

With the added caveat, it has to work on `3.2.57(1)-release`, as I’m on macOS.

I’m pretty sure this isn’t possible, but want to make sure.

Please don’t answer “drop `bash` and use a proper scripting language”. I use other scripting languages as well. `bash` scripts have their place and I like coding them.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way (like a set flag at the top of the script) to make all variables readonly and/or local -r by default?*

No, unless you include editing the source to `bash`.

However, you can declare an alias so that the semantic sugar required to set a variable read-only is reduced.

For example,

```
#!/bin/bash
#
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias lr='local -r'

demo() {
    lr a=123
    echo "$a"
    ((a++))      # Correctly fails with "a: readonly variable"
}

demo
```

Comment: The problem with the answer is that it doesn’t answer the question, which was about changing a behaviour.

Comment: @user137369 thank you. Would you be happier if I started my answer with, "There is no way to invert the declaration of a variable..."?

Answer (score -2):

By using the **declare** function you can make your variables read-only.  When used in a function **declare** makes the variable local.

The syntax for **declare** is this:

`declare arg VARIABLE=value`

To make a variable read-only you use the **-r** argument:

`declare -r num=12`

More can be found here: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_01.html

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but I think it's about as good as you're going to get with BASH

Comment: That still only works on one variable at a time.